# Android TextView offset downwards

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, gravity

I have an activity with two Buttons and a TextView in a LinearLayout.  My TextView is offset downwards and the text doesn't fit inside the box.  Can you explain what is happening?  I think it is related to padding, and I've read several discussions about the perils of TextView padding, but that doesn't explain why the text is cut off at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#800080">

    <Button
        android:text="This"
        android:background="@drawable/button_red" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Button
        android:text="That"
        android:background="@drawable/button_green" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView 
        android:text="Copious amounts of text that overflows onto several lines on a small screen, causing the TextView to dangle below the buttons.  Why it does this I can't imagine.  I only hope someone can help me with this." 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#533f93"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This code produces this display:

[image: User interface]

The purple is the LinearLayout, the blue is the TextView.  As you can see, the TextView's top is below those of the buttons and its bottom is below the bottom of the LinearLayout.  As I add text to the TextView, the LinearLayout increases its height appropriately, but because the TextView is offset, I always lose the bottom of the last line.

I ran Hierarchy Viewer and it gave me this wireframe:

[image: Wireframe image from Hierarchy Viewer]

Which shows the vertical offset at the top, but misses the bottom of the TextView.  The same wireframe with the LinearLayout selected looks like this:

[image: Wireframe image from Hierarchy Viewer - LinearLayout selected]

According to Hierarchy Viewer, the top of the buttons is at 0, but the top of the TextView is at 7.  I've tried various fixes, mostly culled from this site:

```
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

None of these fixed my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `android:baselineAligned` property of your `LinearLayout` to `false`.

From documentation:

> When set to **false**, prevents the layout from aligning its children's
>   baselines. This attribute is particularly useful when the children use
>   different values for gravity. The default value is **true**.

Comment: Yes, that works!  I don't understand why the default is for the LinearLayout to push the text beyond its borders.

Comment: You can read, for example, this post to understand what does [baseline mean](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/1gPy9zo28ak/discussion). So, by default each succeeding widget in `LinearLayout` is baseline-aligned to its preceding widget. In our case **first** line of `TextView` is baseline-aligned to the `Button`'s text. I agree, it is not intuitive behaviour, but it is.

Answer (score 2):

give the layout_gravity of the Textview to be center_vertical

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#800080">

<Button
    android:text="This"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Button
    android:text="That"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView 
    android:text="Copious amounts of text that overflows onto several lines on a small screen, causing the TextView to dangle below the buttons.  Why it does this I can't imagine.  I only hope someone can help me with this." 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#533f93"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Gah!  So easy, thanks!  The default seems to be NONE.  Any idea why by default it pushes the text partially out of sight?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the layout_gravity for the TextView like this:

```
<TextView 
    android:text="Copious amounts of text that overflows onto several lines on a small screen, causing the TextView to dangle below the buttons.  Why it does this I can't imagine.  I only hope someone can help me with this." 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#533f93"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem with several TextViews you can add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to `LinearLayout`